# getting incorrect date while converting web api result

Tags: c#

For a web service call, I am getting back `JSON` result where `sampleValues` returns as sample time in nano seconds (`1579862181821471800`) and sample value for that time.

I tried to hold in a `Dictionary<long, object>` where I am using `long` to hold sample time in nano seconds. Is this correct, do we have any datatype for it in C#?

Next when I tried below code, the date is NOT coming correct. Please suggest.

```
public class Sample
{
    public string SampleId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<long, object> SampleValues { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"[{
                            'sampleId': 'testId',
                            'sampleValues': {
                                '1579862181821471800': 'val1',
                                '1580122686878258600': 'val2' }
                            }]";

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(json);

        foreach(var pair in response.FirstOrDefault().SampleValues)
        {
            var date = new DateTimeOffset((long)(pair.Key * 0.01), TimeSpan.Zero);
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

output, Year is wrong, it should 2020.

> 1/24/0051 10:36:21 AM +00:00
>   1/27/0051 10:58:06 AM +00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your use of `TimeSpan.Zero`, you want to assume that the time is UTC. I would therefore recommend simply replacing the code with the following:

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1579862181821471800 / 1000000)
```

Where `1000000` is the factor between milliseconds and nanoseconds.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/WITQG19609)

I believe your original code didn't work because `Ticks` starts at `DateTime.MinValue`, not `1970-1-1T00:00:00Z`. If we add `621355968000000000` (the number of ticks between `DateTime.MinValue` and the unix epoch datetime) to the value you calculated, your code would also work:

```
long time = (long)((1579862181821471800 * 0.01) + 621355968000000000);
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(time, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

[Example](https://rextester.com/KXDQX46976)

I daresay the first method is simpler :-)

Comment: Thanks John, this works. holding key in `long` data type is fine?

Comment: @user584018 It is until April 2262 :)

Comment: what does mean by until April 2262?

Comment: @user584018 `long.MaxValue` (the biggest number that `long` can hold) is `9223372036854775807`. Taking that value as nanoseconds, the largest date after 1970/01/01 that can be represented in  a `long` is `2262-04-11T23:47:16.854Z`.